Next JS - SignIn funcional con credenciales
Estoy con un problema para el inicio de sesión usando credenciales(es decir, correo y contraseña) ya que al momento de enviar el correo y la contraseña parece que no regresa el objecto de usuario.
Ahorita no estoy usando base de datos, es solo un objecto user que verifica si escribieron el correo y contraseña correctos, lo que quiero es que al momento de verificar que se haga el incio de sesión el objecto usuario se regrese y cambie el sessionStatus a authenticated, utilizando nextAuth.
Este es el archivo donde se hace el inicio de sesión con Providers(Google funciona muy bien)
//api/auth/[nextauth]/route.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/libs/mongodb";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import Auth0Provider from "next-auth/providers/auth0";
import { dateNowUnix } from "@/utils/dates";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
//import User from "@/models/usuarios";



export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET, //process.env.BASE_SECRET,
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  session: { jwt: true }, // Use JSON Web Tokens for session instead of database sessions.
  events: {
    signIn: async (ctx) => {
      //when sign in, update db with last sign in time
      const { user, isNewUser } = ctx;
      try {
        if (isNewUser) {
          user.roles = ["usuario"]; //user 
          user.createdAt = dateNowUnix();
          user.updatedAt = dateNowUnix();
          user.lastLogin = dateNowUnix();
        } else {
          user.lastLogin = dateNowUnix();
        }
        // Save the updated user to the database
        /*const client = await clientPromise;
        await client
          .db()
          .collection("users") //users
          .updateOne({ email: user.email }, { $set: user });*/

          console.log("prueba existosa");
          console.log(`${user.email} logged in`);
          //console.log(`${user.email} logged in and updated in DB =>`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error udating user ${user.email} in signinevent:`, error);
      }
    },
  },
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      authorize(credentials, req){
        const user = {id: "1", name: "isabel", email: "isa@mail.com", password: "12345", roles: ["usuario"] }
                if(credentials?.email === user.email && credentials?.password === user.password){
                    return user;
              }else{
                return null;
              }
            }
    }),
    
    // TODO: Aqui va el otro provider
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  
  // A database is optional, but required to persist accounts in a database
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token}) {
      token.userRole = "usuario" 
      //admin
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
       console.log(session)
      try {
        const client = await clientPromise;
        const user = await client
          .db()
          .collection("users") //users
          .findOne({ email: session.user.email });

        // Add the user's role to the session object
        session.user.roles = user.roles;

        return Promise.resolve(session);
      } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    },
  },
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

El codigo para el form de signIn
"use client"
import Link from "next/link"
import Image from 'next/image';
import CustomButton from '@/components/CustomButton';
import {signIn, useSession} from 'next-auth/react'
import { Navbar2 } from "@/components";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, {FormEventHandler, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import CustomAlert from '@/components/CustomAlert';

export default function Form(){
    // const session = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();
    const { data: session, status: sessionStatus } = useSession();
    const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState(""); // Mensaje de alerta
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (sessionStatus === "authenticated") {
            if(session?.user?.role === "usuario"){
                router.replace("/usuario");
        }else if(session?.user?.role === "terapeuta"){
            router.replace("/terapeuta");
        }else if(session?.user?.role === "admin"){
            router.replace("/admin");
        }
        }else{
            router.replace("/signin");
        }
    }, [sessionStatus, router, session]);

    //const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({email: "", password: ""});
    const handleSubmit/*: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>*/ =  async (e: any) => { //async (e: any)
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = e.target[0].value;
        const password =  e.target[1].value;
       
        //console.log(userInfo);
        /*const res= await signIn ('credentials', {
            email: userInfo.email,
            password: userInfo.password,
            redirect: false,
        });*/
        const res = await signIn('credentials', { //signIn('credentials',
            email,
            password,
            redirect: false,
            
        });
        console.log(res);
        console.log(sessionStatus);
        if (res?.error ) { //
            setAlertMessage("Contraseña y/o correo eléctronico incorrecto");
            setIsVisible(true);
            //if (res?.url) router.replace("/usuario");
        }
        
    };

    if (sessionStatus === "loading") {
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    }

    return(
        <>
        <Navbar2 />

        <main className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full flex-1 bg-[#F5FFFC]">
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div className="flex max-w-3xl yellowContainer"> {/*div principal */}
                {/*Sección de iniciar sesión*/}
                <div className="logoContainer"> 
                    <Image
                        src="/atomo.png"
                        alt="atomo"
                        width={80}
                        height={48}
                        className="object-contain mx-auto logoSignIn" 
                    />
                    <div className="divYellowContainer"><h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center titleSignIn">Iniciar Sesión</h1><br />
                        <div className="flex flex-col w-full pl-4">
                            <form className="flex flex-col items-center w-full" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>                                 
                                <input type="email" /*value={userInfo.email} onChange={({target}) => setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, email: target.value})}*/ className="bg-white rounded-lg outline-none text-base h-12 pl-2 w-3/4 input" placeholder="Correo" />
                                <br />
                                <input type="password" /*value={userInfo.password} onChange={({target}) => setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, password: target.value})}*/ className="bg-white rounded-lg outline-none text-base h-12 pl-2 w-3/4 input" placeholder="Contraseña" />
                            
                                <CustomButton
                                    btnType="submit"
                                    title="Iniciar Sesión"
                                    containerStyles="text-white rounded-full bg-[#FC83A1] hover:bg-[#E55E7F] font-medium mt-10 textButton"
                                />
                            </form><br />
                            <div className="flex justify-between">
                                <p className="text-black text-[17px] font-medium prSignIn">¿No tienes cuenta? <Link href="/signup" className="text-[#E55E7F]">Regístrate</Link></p>
                                <p className="text-black text-[17px] font-medium prSignIn"><Link href="" className="text-[#E55E7F]">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</Link></p>
                            </div>
                            {/* Renderizar alerta */}
                            {isVisible && (
                                <CustomAlert
                                    status="warning"
                                    variant="subtle"
                                    title="Error"
                                    description={alertMessage}
                                    setIsVisible={setIsVisible}
                                />
                            )}                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div className="flex flex-nowrap items-center justify-center">
                            <div className="border-2 border-[#FC83A1] inline-block mb-2 pinkLine"></div>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <p className="text-black text-[15px] font-bold">O</p>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <div className="border-2 border-[#FC83A1] inline-block mb-2 pinkLine"></div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div className="flex justify-center my-2">&nbsp;
                        <button onClick={() => signIn('google', { callbackUrl: '/usuario' })} /*'/terapeuta' */ className="flex items-center justify-center w-[299px] h-[59px] 
                        border-2 border-[#FFFFFF] bg-[#FFFFFF] rounded px-2 py-2 font-light text-center"> <Image
                        src="/buscar.png"
                        alt="mental"
                        width={40}
                        height={40}
                        className="mr-2 googleLogo" 
                        />Continuar con Google</button> {/*'google', { callbackUrl: '/dashboard' }*/ }
                        </div> <br /> 
                        <br />
                </div>
            </div> <br />
        </main>
        </>
    )
}

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho :(
